# how i can make find method does not make a problem

Tags: php, oop, backend

i create a Depot class. when i create object from this class i use find method for find a Special item with id.

after that i cant call any other method.

**I do not use Laravel**

```php
// index.php file
$depot = new Depot();
$depot = $depot->find(2);
var_dump($depot->hi());
```

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::hi()

hi method is for test.

```php
// model.php file
class Model {
// ...
public function find(int $id)
    {
        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare("select * from {$this->table} where id = :id");
        $statement->execute(compact('id'));
        $obj = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $obj;
    }
}
```

```php
class Depot extends Model {
//...
public function hi()
    {
        echo "hi";
    }

}
```

Comment: `find()` in this scenario returns the result of calling [`PDOStatement::fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php), of which I wouldn’t expect there to be a method `hi()` - you’re replacing `$depot` with this result. This doesn’t appear to be your intention - review the logic you’re using to store the result and be sure it aligns with your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

With this line:

```
$depot = $depot->find(2);
```

you're overwriting the variable `$depot`, representing your object, with the result of your query. The object returned (unsurprisingly) doesn't contain a function called `hi()`.

I don't know if this was just a typo, but if not, it's generally a sign of poor code quality if you re-use the same variable to contain two completely different things. It leads to maintenance and readability issues, and often causes errors further down the line, such as this one, where you mistakenly assume the variable still has its original content. Weakly-typed languages such as PHP are especially vulnerable to this kind of mistake. The easiest thing is to just make a rule never to do it.

Assigning the result to a different variable, e.g.

```
$depot = new Depot();
$findResult = $depot->find(2);
$depot->hi();
```

will fix the issue.

(Also the `var_dump()` was unnecessary since `hi()` already contains an echo.)

Comment: Although this stops the error, it makes the `find()` call pointless.  I'm assuming they want to retrieve the values from the database into an object of type `Depot`

Comment: @NigelRen maybe? It doesn't say that anywhere and it's far from obvious if that's definitely the case. Certainly the code makes no attempt to convert the PDO result into a `Depot` object. OP needs to clarify if that's the case. I took it as either a typo or a misunderstanding of return types. Besides, they already declared a `Depot` - it's unclear if `find` should maybe populate the object it's a member of instead of returning a raw result set. If it was meant to return a new `Depot` object then it ought to be `static` really IMO.

Comment: i want find item with id 2 and Get related products ex: $depot->products();

Comment: @Mesh that doesn't really explain anything specific in relation to this situation. Can you be clearer about what exactly should happen?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$depot = new Depot();
$depotDb = $depot->find(2);
var_dump($depot->hi());
```

Comment: How will this help?  You now ignore the return value from finding anything.